# Database Automatic Song Planner should not choose same song

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, solr, similarity

Short intro:
Music Studio program which runs on a mysql/mssql database and randomly chooses songs from the song table.

Problem: the same songs exists on multiple cd's, so the same song could be choosen multiple times, which shouldn't happen. Big question: How to avoid this because the names are not always exactly the same.

(Other rules that should be applied when choosing a song:

- LastPlayedTime more than X minutes.
- Shoud not exist in current queue-playlist (the song has already been choosen te be played in near future).
- Rating > 1 (Can be 0-10)
  )

I cannot change the structure of my database, otherwise the Music Studio would break. But I can use a secondary database like SOLR or MongoDB or... to grab

some song-id's to put on the queue-playlist.

I was thinking: choose a song that shoud not match 10% of a song in the history (lastplayedtimestamp or history table) or in the queuelist (table).

Is something possible with SOLR for example?

(I only need the songid to instruct the musicstudio to put the song on the queue list).

Song-table structure:

Example:

```
Id, Artist,                       Title,                         Filename (usually Artist - Title . Extension).
1,  Narcotic Thrust,              I Like It (ORIGINAL MIX) 2004, C:\library\Dance X 2004\Narcotic Thrust - I Like It (ORIGINAL MIX) 2004.mp3
2,  Narcotic Thrust,              I Like It,                     C:\library\Dance CD 2005 vol.1\410-narcotic_thrust-i_like_it.flac
6,  01 Inna featuring Bob Taylor, Deja Vu,                       C:\library\Cool Dance CD vol.3\201 Inna featuring Bob Taylor - Deja Vu.mp3
7,  Inna (feat.) Bob Taylor,      Deja Vu,                       C:\library\Best Dance CD vol.9\08.Inna feat bob taylor - Deja Vu.mp3
8,  Inna,                         Déjà Vu,                       c:\library\D-Dance vol.2\206-inna-deja_vu.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

The task is a non-trivial one as it might not be even possible to detect duplicated songs without resorting to run statistical analysis *on the song themselves* rather than on their titles but assuming that in most cases meta data about the song will have a lot in common you could achieve the sufficient results with locality-sensitive hashing where near-duplicates will receive similar hashes. Similarity in turn is measured in Hamming distances.

The solution I propose is to run [Simhash](http://matpalm.com/resemblance/simhash/) on the Artist, Title and Filename combined. You could prepare the strings with some [stemmer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stemming/1.0), then you measure the said Hamming distance and if crosses the threshold (you need to define it) then you will now that it is most likely a duplicate.

In essence, what you will be doing will be searching for near duplicates - see also the link below for more detailed explanation
http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/tts/pdf/dup-2x2.pdf

Regarding the part of your question referring to solr, the link below is the closest I could get. I have never used it though, so can't tell much about it.
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_2/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/TextProfileSignature.html
and
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TextProfileSignature

Comment: To get Solr to display only one result for a group of duplicates, I would suggest to use its' [Result Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping). You would then group on the field populated by Simhash.